# Editing the name and check for duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to edit an option of a dropdown and check if the newly edited option is already present in the dropdown. 
If it is, it should give an alert, else edit and add the new option in the dropdown.

But there is a case when user clicks edit but then doesn't want to change the name and clicks OK (as that option is in the dropdown it gives alert that the option is already present).

How to check this excluding the option which I am editing?

```
function IsNameAlreadyPresent(DropdownID,Name){
    var Result = false;
    $.each($("#"+DropdownID+" option"),function(i,e){
        if(e.innerHTML == Name){
            Result = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return Result;
}

function EditOptionName() {
    var Name = $("#txtName").val(); 
    if(IsNameAlreadyPresent('DropdownId',Name)) {
        alert("Name \"" + Name + "\" already exists. \nPlease type an unique name.")
    }
    else{       
        $('#DropdownId').find(':selected').text($('#txtName').val()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should keep the state in a way, and that starts when the user clicks edit. Which code is not present in your sample if I'm right? State could be OriginalValue or EditingOption.

Comment: is `l_sResult` a typo?

Comment: yes it was a typo. corrected

Comment: code shown is changing text of existing option not adding an option. Is that what is intended? Where is the event handling code that is using this? If you want to abort need to be able to connect to it

Comment: yes. this is what I am expecting but the case where its failing is when the user clicks edit but then changes mind to edit the option and wants to keep the same text . it gives error.

Comment: create  a simple demo showing this being used with appropriate buttons to make change and  to cancel

Comment: its not cancelled but clicked ok to keep the same option.

Comment: not understanding this UI...demo would help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85160/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Why did you set the `Result` to `true` inside your `if` test then `return false` after?

Comment: @J.Lucky I think he wants to break immediately from `$.each` function

Comment: @mr5, I see thanks. Why `false` tho?

Comment: @J.Lucky Don't have any idea why it's `false`. One could return any data type from it. I think he just want to exit from the loop after the condition satisfies him and not to evaluate any more unnecessary code, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check first that the user has actually edited the value or selected the previous value only. Store this in a flag variable say 'modified'. Then use the below code:

```
function EditOptionName() {
    var Name = $("#txtName").val(); 
    var modified;
    if(IsNameAlreadyPresent('DropdownId',Name) && modified) {
        alert("Name \"" + Name + "\" already exists. \nPlease type an unique name.")
    }
    else{       
        $('#DropdownId').find(':selected').text($('#txtName').val()); 
    }
}
```